# I found a mossy thing on my plant

Tags: species-identification

I was just wondering if this is a moss and if so what type of moss[image]

Comment: looks like a moss to me. A bryologist or local botany expert would be best suited. Where are you located? What plant? Having a picture of this directly on your plant would be best.

Comment: I agree it's moss. Like most plant ID, a close up (I know it's tiny; can you crop and enlarge?) and in its habitat (on your plant) is important. Thanks! (Pretty, too.)

Comment: Definitely moss. Which one depends strongly on where you are in the world. There are about 12,000 species in total. For proper ID we would need to be able to see the leaf, particularly the nerve (if present) and cells at the base of the leaf under magnification with a hand lens or microscope, as well as habitat (what type of environment you found it in) and habit - how it grows.